# c# mvc pdf download fails on android chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, model-view-controller, download

first time question here, so let me know if i'm doing it wrong...

My C# MVC5 app lets users download pdf files.  It works great except on my android phone.  I'm using chrome and letting the OS handle the PDF.  It looks like it's using the Google Drive apps' build in PDF viewer.

When i use a direct link to the file it works fine, but when i download it through a controller action it fails with "file is of invalid format".  I've simplified it to a test case for this question.

So here's my action method:

```
public ActionResult IndirectTestFile()
{
string filename = "document.pdf";

var disposition = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition("inline") { FileName = filename };
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", disposition.ToString());

string serverFilename = Server.MapPath("~/files/direct/" + filename);
return File(serverFilename, "application/pdf");
}
```

and my HTML:

```
//This fails:
<a href="/report/indirectTestFile">Indirect link to file</a>

//This works:
<a href="/Files/direct/Document.pdf">Direct link to file</a>
```

I'm using windows (desktop) Chrome to get the headers for these request.

Here's the response headers for direct link:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/pdf
Last-Modified: Thu, 07 Jul 2016 11:46:47 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "b8a3dd3d45d8d11:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 07 Jul 2016 12:33:05 GMT
Content-Length: 51793
```

And the response headers for link to the MVC action:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: application/pdf
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=document.pdf
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 07 Jul 2016 12:34:09 GMT
Content-Length: 51793
```

I don't see any huge differences there, but one is reliably working, and the other is reliably failing.

it's not a corrupt download.  If i download the 'bad' PDF on windows and copy it to the android phone, the same viewer is happy to show it!

Anyone see this before?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future searchers:

I haven't solved this problem but i did find out exactly what the cause was. Looking though my logs, it looks like the google drive/docs app is handling the download instead of the browser.  The request comes through with a different user agent to the browser.

That means it happens in a different session. That session isn't logged in to the web site, so instead of downloading the PDF, it's redirected to the login page and downloads that, and complains it's not a valid PDF file! So that's why it happens.

I tested that by removing the authentication from the controller, so the request isn't redirected, and the pdf downloads and displays ok.

I can't figure out why chrome handles the direct download itself, but passes the controller link off to the google app.  I changed my server so that both requests pass back the same headers, so i'm oblivious to how chrome can tell the difference between the two and treat them differently, but it does.

I either need to figure that out or re-organise my app to get around this problem, but maybe that's for a different question.

Thanks to Fran for the ideas.

**Update:**
I don't recall the exact solution to this (so sad, it was only a few weeks ago...), but i think it was because i was redirecting to the my controller action.  e.g. i would have an action like this (simplified)

```
    public ActionResult MakePDF(string id)
    {
        // code to create the file removed for clarity.
        return RedirectToAction("IndirectTestFile");
    }
```

this would make the PDF file and redirect to an action that returns it to the user.

So i cut out the redirect like this

```
    public ActionResult MakePDF(string id)
    {
        // code to create the file removed for clarity.
        return IndirectTestFile();
    }
```

and that seems to be the solution - i'm using this method anyway and it's working for me.

Comment: I'm having this same exact problem.  Will you post an update if you find anything?  I'll continue to research as well.

Comment: So it looks like this is caused by the Content-Disposition header.  I've tried various things to make it work, but I haven't had much luck.  If you don't try to inline it, Chrome just downloads it.

Comment: The only difference i saw with Content-Disposition was if you set it to attachment, you are telling chrome to download it, so it downloads it, so there's no need to pass it off to the google drive app.

Comment: @Danation - added an update above for you.  I guess if android chrome sees a link to a PDF it will download it, but if it sees a redirect to a PDF it will hand it off?  It doesn't quite make sense given my original post, but that's how I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

When I write a pdf, I use a custom PdfResult

```
public class PdfResult : FileResult
{
    private const String DefaultFileName = "file.pdf";
    private readonly Byte[] _byteArray;

    public PdfResult(Byte[] byteArray, String fileName = DefaultFileName)
        : base(MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf)
    {
        _byteArray = byteArray;
        FileDownloadName = fileName;
    }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response) { response.BinaryWrite(_byteArray); }
}
```

I would change you controller action to use the PdfResult, passing in the bytes of the file.  you can get the bytes by using File.ReadAllBytes.

```
public ActionResult IndirectTestFile()
{
string filename = "document.pdf";

var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/files/direct/" + filename));
return new PdfResult(fileBytes, filename);
}
```

You second link

```
<a href="/Files/direct/Document.pdf">Direct link to file</a>
```

works because the browser is doing the work on reading the file directly.

Comment: Hi Fran, i tried your code but can't tell if it works as it uses content-disposition:attachment to force a download.

The download works fine and can be viewed, but it can't be viewed inline.  Can this be adapted to be inline rather than an attachment?

I'm not sure if there's much difference here except it is a different way to load the file into the stream?

Comment: You say the browser is downloading the 2nd link directly - as i understand it, the browser is downloading both links in exactly the same way.  Either the browser is downloading them both or the PDF viewer is.  It doesn't make sense that the browser would download one but the PDF viewer would be downloading the other.  Maybe i'm wrong?

Comment: what I meant was that your first link puts asp.net mvc in the middle. an anchor tag with an href to the exact file isn't going to go through a controller action. so an a tag will be interpreted however the browser interprets an a tag.

Comment: Do you even need to go through a controller action?  why not just gave directly links to the files?

Comment: Have you seen this https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/xkkVSoLSIxo

Comment: That looks like the exact problem alright, but they have no solution.  Made me look in my logs though and i think i found the problem.
I have this exact problem.

It looks like google drive is handling the download instead of the browser (different user agent).  That means it happens in a different session. That session isn't logged in to the web site, so instead of downloading the PDF, it's redirected to the login page and downloads that, and complains it's not a valid PDF file!

So that's why it happens, but how can i work around that?  I can't allow unauthenticated downloads. (glum)